# Nexus Artifact Upload Plugin does not fail pipeline, if upload fails

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, nexus

I have created a declarative pipeline which

1. Builds the artifact using maven
2. Uploads the artifact to Nexus repository

Plugins Used-
Nexus Artifact Uploader Plugin

Nexus-
Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.17

But here, when the upload artifact to nexus repo fails, pipeline does not fail, it shows as success. I checked that many other people have reported this issue.

So can I add any workaround here, to fail my pipeline if upload fails?

I have attached the publish artifact stage and the screenshot

```
    stage("Publish to Nexus") {

    environment { 
                        tag_version= sh (returnStdout: true, script: 'mvn -f core build-helper:parse-version help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout').trim()
                    }
    steps {

        sh 'echo "tag_version=$tag_version"'

        script {
                    
                    nexusArtifactUploader(
                        nexusVersion: NEXUS_VERSION,
                        protocol: NEXUS_PROTOCOL,
                        nexusUrl: NEXUS_URL,
                        groupId: "com.cable",
                        version: tag_version,
                        repository: NEXUS_REPOSITORY,
                        credentialsId: NEXUS_CREDENTIAL_ID,
                        artifacts: [
                            // Artifact generated such as .jar, .ear and .war files.
                            [artifactId: 'core',
                            classifier: '',
                            file: "./core/target/core-$tag_version-jar-with-dependencies.jar",
                            type: 'jar'],
                        ]
                    );

                
            }
        }
    }
```

Console Output

```
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.cable:core:jar:8.6.1 from/to snapshots (https://nexus.yo-digital.com/repository/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: https://nexus.yo-digital.com/repository/snapshots/com/cable/core/8.6.1/core-8.6.1.jar. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase:Repository version policy: SNAPSHOT does not allow version: 8.6.1.
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // script
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // withEnv
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // withEnv
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // withEnv
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // withEnv
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // withEnv
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // ws
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: The error says "SNAPSHOT does not allow version: 8.6.1". Is there an artifact with that version string already? You could try a different version.

Comment: Yes, there is already an artifact with same version. That is why, it is throwing an error. But my question is, since there is an error the pipeline should fail. But in the end it show Success message.

Answer (score 2):

I found that this is an issue with the plugin (Nexus Artifact Uploader). So in order to fail the pipeline if any such condition occurs, we can add a stage which will check the console output logs, and will fail the pipeline if any "error" string appears.

```
        stage('Results') 
        {
           steps 
           {
              script 
              {
                  def logz = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(10000);
                  def result = logz.find { it.contains('Failed to deploy artifacts') }
                  if (result) 
                  {
                     error (result)
                  }
               }
            }
         }
```